# how to modularize powershell scripts

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, chef-infra

I'm a programmer, though new to powershell. I am scripting tasks/configurations such as these:

[image]

1. I would like to be able to run these with some type of "wrapper" that can manage errors, and handle execution flow
2. I would be running these in both Azure and on-premises environments
3. We would like to have a good logging and diagnostics built in.

**How should small powershell scripts be wrapped in a way to make the solution modular and testable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For at least some of these tasks, it sounds like you would be better served by using a Configuration Management framework like [PowerShell Desired State Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

1. Errors are handled or reported, state is ensured (attempted), execution happens on a schedule or manually.
2. Runs in Azure or on-prem.
3. Logging and diagnostics are built-in and part of it.

Of course other CM solutions like Puppet and Chef are available as well.